# Django - Accessing through ManyToMany extra field in template

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have the following Model Structures :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    publish     = models.BooleanField()
    cover       = models.ForeignKey(GenericMedia, related_name='+')
    media       = models.ManyToManyField(GenericMedia, through='AssocProjectMedia')
    credits     = models.ManyToManyField(AssocTitleName)

class GenericMedia(models.Model):
    limit           = models.Q(model = 'Image') | models.Q(model = 'Other')
    content_type    = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to = limit)
    object_id       = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object  = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" % os.path.basename(self.content_object.url.name)

    def instance(self):
        return self.content_object.__class__.__name__


class AssocProjectMedia(models.Model):
    project     = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    media       = models.ForeignKey(GenericMedia)

    position    = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    grid_size   = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null = True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

I have been trying for a while to get the position data (includes in AssocProjectMedia) in my template with the following :

in my view :

```
project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=project_slug)
    return render(request, 'projects/projects_details.html', {"project":project})
```

in my template :

```
{% for media in project.media_set.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

But this doesn't work, nothing appear.

If instead I write:

```
{% for media in project.media.all %}
...
{% endfor %}
```

I will get my media data but not the one included in the through model (AssocProjectMedia).

If anyone has an idea on how to do that...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

```
{% for assoc_media in project.assocprojectmedia_set.all %}
    {{assoc_media.position}}
    {# or whatever field #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Oh it's work thanks ! Is it possible to change the related_name of the 'through' relation ?

Comment: Is it possible to get only one row based on some filter instead of assocprojectmedia_set.all() in the template? e.g, i would like to get position where project=xx, media=xx